# How to get $T(n) = 2^n$?

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

how do i arrive from the  recurrence $T(n) = 1 +$ $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} T(j)$

to $T(n) = 2 ^ {n}$ ?

where $T(0) = 1$

Comment: Use strong induction over $n$ .

Comment: (Also note that the recurrence can be transformed to $T(n)=2T(n-1)$.)

Comment: Okay what if the $2^{n}$ wasn't given? Also how is it equal to 2T(n-1) if you don't mind explaining?

Comment: Makes sense :). Thank you.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Can you be more specific about algorithm X? I can't find any such in the Contents or Index. Thanks.

Comment: @Cye Sorry, I meant algorithm Hyper, of course. (Algorithm X is for Sudoku :))

Comment: The question you ask is very reasonable! (In fact, finding the right „tricks“ in math is very difficult in general.) Note that for $n\ge 1$,
$$T(n-1)=1+\sum_{k=0}^{n−2} T(k)$$
from the recurrence. Therefore,
$$T(n)=T(n−1)+1+\sum_{k=0}^{n−2}T(k)=2T(n−1).$$
There are algorithmic ways to solve recurrence relations, such as algorithm Hyper, described in chapter 8 of the book *A=B* by Herbert Wilf, Doron Zeilberger and Marko Petkovsek.

Comment: @Cye to avoid confusion I have re-posted my comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's prove this by induction:

Claim: $T(n) = 1 + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}T(j) = 2^n$

Base Case: $T(1) = 1 + \sum_{j=0}^{0}T(j) = 1 + T(0) = 2 = 2^1$

Inductive Step: Given that for all  i, such that $0\leq i \leq k$, $T(i) = 2^{i}$, let's prove $T(k+1) = 2^{k+1}$.

\begin{align}
T(k+1) = 1 + \sum_{j=0}^{k}T(j) = 1 + \frac{1-2^{k+1}}{1-2} = 1 + 2^{k+1}-1 = 2^{k+1}
\end{align}

Both the base case and the inductive step is proved, thus the claim is proved.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the result is false and let $n$ be the smallest positive integer such that $T(n)\ne 2^n$. Note that $T(0)=1$.

Then $T(n)=1+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} T(j)=1+(1+2+ ... +2^{n-1})=1+(2^n-1)=2^n$.

Hence there is no counterexample!

Comment: How would you know that T(n) = 1 + (1 + 2 + ... + $n^{n-1}$) ? How do you know that it's a summation of powers of 2 without calculating all of them?

Comment: All I have done is substituted for the 'smaller' $T(j)$ since these are powers of $2$ (since the first counterexample is $T(n)$.

Comment: Okay, i get it. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true for $n=0$: $T_0=1=2^0$. Suppose it is true for $n$: $T_n=2^n$. Then by the recursion formula $T_{n+1}=T_n+T_n=2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}$ and the statement is proved by induction.

Comment: I don't understand why $T_{n+1} = T_{n}+T_{n}$? could you explain this more?

Comment: $T_{n+1}=(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} T_i)+T_n=T_n+T_n$,

Answer (score 0):

$T(n+1)- T(n)= 1 + \sum_{j=0}^{n}T(j) -[ 1 + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}T(j)] = T(n)$

That is $T(n+1)=2T(n)$ which is geometric sequence with $T(0)=0$, so  we get $$ T(n)= T(0) 2^n= 2^n.$$